# MaxSNP flow problems

Tags: complexity-theory, approximation, network-flow

Currently, I'm trying to understand the definition and notion of [MaxSNP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNP_%28complexity%29) and MaxSNP-hardness. I see that several combinatorical problems such as Max-3SAT are in MaxSNP since one can easily express them as first order predicates quantified over the set of all structures.

The question is: Is the definition of MaxSNP applicable to flow problems? I'm struggling with the formulation of a flow problem, which incorporates sets of real numbers rather than discrete sets of elements as solutions, as first-order predicates. For example, are the traditional max flow and min-cost flow problems in MaxSNP? (clearly, it's not MaxSNP-hard, but is it in MaxSNP?)

Comment: What *is* the definition of MaxSNP?